# How do you lookup a value in Excel against a list of wildcard possibilities? AHRI wildcard information

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, wildcard, lookup

I've been racking my brain for the past few weeks trying to "decode" a list of products and determine an easy way to check a value against what I would best describe as an "input mask."

The table that contains the value I'm looking for contains a value that has multiple wildcards.

Ex. `48FC**04***5*` or `48LC**04*2*1A*****`

The value I'd be searching for is an active/inactive flag in the same table as the wildcard. But, I only have the actual string in the cell of my lookup value. Ex. `48FC000406850`

The wildcards are not in the same places most of the time, and the length of each string varies throughout.

The approximation parameters in VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP, and INDEX/MATCH will get me there 80% of the way, but I can't afford this to be less than 100% accurate. It's also too difficult to predefine every value; there are 130,000 unique "masks".

In the table below, I used the approximation for VLOOKUP and it returned the wrong result.

| String | Active/Inactive | Lookup Value | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `48FC**04***1*` | Active | `48FC0660001` | `48FC**06***6*` |
| `48FC**04***3*` | Active | Formula | Expected Result |
| `48FC**04***5*` | Active | =VLOOKUP(C2,B:B,1,1) | `48FC**06***1*` |
| `48FC**04***6*` | Active |  |  |
| `48FC**05***1*` | Active |  |  |
| `48FC**05***3*` | Active |  |  |
| `48FC**05***5*` | Active |  |  |
| `48FC**05***6*` | Active |  |  |
| `48FC**06***1*` | Inactive |  |  |
| `48FC**06***3*` | Inactive |  |  |
| `48FC**06***5*` | Inactive |  |  |
| `48FC**06***6*` | Inactive |  |  |

Comment: Is the lookup value of `48FC660001` a typo here? If it was intended to match the  `48FC**06***1*` pattern then the `06` part of the pattern doesn't match anything in the lookup value

Comment: Is `*` intended to match a single character?

Comment: You may need to loop over the masks and check your input value against each one (maybe using `Like`, and if those `*` represent single characters you'd need to replace them with `?`)  If there are no variable prefixes then you could improve performance by segregating your masks according to the first few fixed characters.  https://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/

Comment: @barrowc, that was a typo, correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Replace multiple "*" by multiple "?" (wilcards as usual).

To check if values match your masks:

```
' Returns true if pSearched matches pPattern with wildcards
' Needs reference "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"
Function RegexMatch(ByVal pSearched As String, ByVal pPattern As String, _
    Optional ByVal pIgnoreCase As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    Dim rRegex As Object
    
    Set rRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    pPattern = Replace(pPattern, ".", "[.]")
    pPattern = Replace(pPattern, "*", ".*")
    pPattern = Replace(pPattern, "?", ".")
    With rRegex
        .IgnoreCase = pIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = pPattern
    End With
    RegexMatch = rRegex.test(pSearched)
End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print RegexMatch("48FC660001", "48FC??0001*")          'True
    Debug.Print RegexMatch("48FC660001", "48FC*000*")            'True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this gets me part of the way there. The two lists I have are 148,000 rows by three columns to compare against 36,000 rows by 1 column. I'm trying to think of an alternative to a "Do Loop" and running this against every line. Could I declare pSearched as a range instead?

Answer (score 0):

In `D2`, enter formula :

```
=INDEX(A2:A13,MATCH(1,INDEX(0+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2:A13,C2)),0),0)
```

[image]